# Reverse proxy Kibana 7 with ARR in IIS

Tags: kibana, iis-7.5, arr, kibana-7

I set up some days ago an ELK 7 stack to monitor some logs in one place. For now it perfectly operational and works well from inside the network. I now want to access Kibana from outside the network without the need of a VPN.

I already have a website running in IIS which is served through a global reverse proxy. The website itself is doing nothing but there are 2 WebApplications under it (there's just a little app at the webiste root doing a redirect to the right app depending of the source of the request).

So at the moment, i have the following URLs available (servername could be either my machine name when i'm on the intranet or the external domain when i'm remoting) :

- http(s)://servername/app1
- http(s)://servername/app2

Now i would like to be able to get the following URL working to access Kibana

- http(s)://servername/elk

For now i didn't manage to make it work - even internally - (so without involving the first global reverse proxy).

I set up a application under a website dedicated for testing purpose (so it won't mess with the real website). This is an extract of my web.config file for this application :

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="KibanaProxy">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://kibanahost:5601/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="KibanaRedirect" preCondition="Redirect">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Location" pattern="^/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="/elk/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="KibanaContent" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Input, Link, Script" pattern="^/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="/elk/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I wrote a rule to handle the first redirect done when accessing the Kibana root and i tried to add a rewrite rule so external resources can be accessed also. It seems like i have still some other rewrites to do mainly because of URL inside bootstrap.js and such things like CSS... It seems like it's a pain to achieve and i wonder if anyone managed to accomplish such a proxying. If i can proxy Kibana correctly internally, i would be able to add an authentication layer thanks to IIS before trying to expose it over the internet through the global reverse proxy.

Comment: Is the current configuration file useless? What is the impact of using this configuration file?

Comment: @DingPeng Sorry for the late answer. This configuration file is not useless. It allows me to acces the root of Kibana and handle the redirect correctly but everything is wrong after as it seems like all internal URLS (inside CSS, JS) are not rewrited correctly. And then i have an error page...